# What is 'Agni Dei in sugar'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pop-culture

I am reading 'A Dog of Flanders' and here is the sentence that includes the phrase: *She had neither brother nor sister; her blue serge dress had never a hole in it; at Kermesse she had as many gilded nuts and **Agni Dei in sugar** as her hands could hold*.

In here, *she* refers to 'Alois', who is Nello's friend.

Comment: It seems that you have been busy asking https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20180614074330AAl5Zw4&guccounter=1 . I think that this question got nothing to do with English Language. Agni dei seems to be some sort of Dutch sweet  typical at Kermesse. Notice that no image of such sweet can be found, at least in the first pages of results from Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess they are sweets made in the shape of lambs:

[Agnus Dei](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Agnus%20Dei): (plural, Agni Dei)

- an image of a lamb often with a halo and a banner and cross used as a symbol of Christ.

[image]

(M-W)

Comment: As the link shows, **Agnus Dei** is the singular. The author is using the Latin plural form _agni_ =lambs.

Comment: The dictionary definition is for **Agnus** not *Agni*, it seems to be a [Polish tradition](http://briansibleysblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/agnus-dei.html), which explains why I have never heard or seen it despite attending an Irish Catholic school as a child, and having being brought up in an Italian Catholic family

Comment: @Mari-LouA - interesting finding. I’m not familiar with that tradition, too. Anyway there are a lot of different local traditions among people who follow the same religion. They probably date back centuries.

Comment: I don't know.... but speaking as a former Roman Catholic person, there is only *one* lamb of God. I think the "Agni" is an error committed by the speaker (or author)

Comment: @Mari-LouA- I don’t think it is a mistake. Here Agni  just means lambs, the sugar Lambs  she hold in her hands. The religious reference is obvious, though.

Comment: I understand why the speaker or narrator uses the plural form, but it's like saying "lambs of God", which sounds a little sacrilegious, maybe immigrant Polish children called these sugar lambs, "agni"? I don't know.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - maybe, there are other usage instances in the plural, though, like: “*But the nuns of Le Murate sent consignments of hand-made gifts to their patron, the queen of Portugal, **that included several agni dei in gold and silver**  and 'an image' of the Virgin.”* https://www.google.com/search?q=%22agni%20dei%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1978,cd_max:2005&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: Using [marzipan](http://traditionscustoms.com/religion/baranek-wielkanocny) seems an easier way of making and (eating?) these lambs. [*An absolute 'must' for the Holy Saturday food blessing is the Easter lamb, usually made of sugar or butter, but it can also be a non-edible figure made of plaster, wood, cloth or plastic and should go into the basket last, because in effect it watches over the rest of the ingredients.*](https://www.tasteofpl.com/products/polish-large-laying-easter-lamb-baranek-wielkanocny-7-5-long?variant=14458894598)

Comment: Ha! They have them in Sicily as well... I live and learn something new http://www.italyadvisor.co.uk/sicilian-easter-marzipan-lambs/